How many solutions can an equation with negative (but integer) exponents have?
A polynomial of degree $n$ cannot have more than $n$ solutions. However, a polynomial can only have nonnegative powers. What about an equation that has negative integer powers? Is there any analogous rule or regularity for the number of solutions such an equation can have?

You can always multiply such an equation with a power of $x$
to make it a polynomial equation.

Thank you, Martin R. Not a general rule to determine the number of solutions but still useful for my puposes. Simple but effective!

Martin's answer essentially says if the highest power term is $x^n$ and the lowest is $x^{-m}$ then you can re-write this as a polynomial with highest power term $x^{n+m}$ and the function can then have up to $n+m$ roots (depending on whether you are solving over reals, allowing for repeated roots...)

@RedFive, indeed, after thinking again about Martin's answer, I wonder whether it helps at all to multiply the "polynomial" with a power of $x$. As you illustrate correctly with your example, if I multiply the original expression by $x^{-m}$, I potentially change the number of solutions. But the number of solutions of the original expression is what I want to know. Therefore, the question stands: Is there a shortcut to determine the maximal number of solutions of a "polynomial with negative exponents", by which I mean a way to find out without solving the equation?

I think $n+m$ is still the maximum. Whether or not this maximum always occurs depends on how you count the roots and other features of the polynomial (if it has no constant term then $x=0$ is a potential issue, for example).

@Florian: If there is at least one negative exponent then $x=0$ is not a solution, so that multiplication with a power of $x$ does not change the number of solutions.
